# What is Source Connector Inbound,Source Connector Inbound and Destination 1 Outbound in Mirth?

Tags: mirth, outbound, inbound

What is Source Connector Inbound,Source Connector Outbound and Destination 1 Outbound in Mirth means? And which case these be used.
I searched on Mirth forum but didn't get satisfactory answer.
I'm unable to sense these 3 concepts.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for typo. The second one is Source Connector Outbound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the third concept is, as you repeated Source Connector Inbound twice.

In general, a Mirth Channel represents a transformation of an incoming message to one or more actions and/or outgoing messages. A channel consists of a single Source Connector and one or more Destination Connectors.

The Source Connector defines how you receive your inbound message. It could be a traditional LLP listener that is receiving messages from a client on a TCP connection, it could be a file reader which monitors an FTP site for uploaded message batches, a database reader which monitors for changed records in an EMR system, etc.

The Destination Connectors define what you do with the data or message once you have it. Destination Connectors can be given any name you choose, but the default name for the first Destination Connector in a Channel is always "Destination 1". Destination Connectors allow you to do things like save message data to a database, generate a new or transformed message that is based on the incoming message and send it by a variety of mechanisms, create a PDF or HTML document, etc.

This [blog post](http://irwinj.blogspot.com/2008/12/getting-started-with-mirth-part-1_18.html) is four years old but still provides a useful introduction to the very basics.